# ssh localhost not working, authenticity of host can't be established

Tags: macos, ssh

After checking permissions on `$HOME` and `.ssh` and running recommended commands am still having trouble getting ssh localhost to work without password. Below is edited history of my commands and output from `ssh -vvv localhost`. It is failing to load `id_rsa` and I can not figure out why. Running on Max OSX yosemite 10.10.5

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

I have remote login enabled from preferences.

```
zak-keirns-imac:~ zak$ ls -l .ssh
total 40
-rw-------  1 zak  staff  2252 Dec 13 12:28 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 zak  staff   668 Dec 13 12:28 id_dsa
-rw-r--r--  1 zak  staff   615 Dec 13 12:28 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------  1 zak  staff  1679 Dec 13 11:28 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 zak  staff   407 Dec 13 11:28 id_rsa.pub
zak-keirns-imac:~ zak$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
/Users/zak/.ssh/id_dsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Your identification has been saved in /Users/zak/.ssh/id_dsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/zak/.ssh/id_dsa.pub.
zak-keirns-imac:~ zak$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
zak-keirns-imac:~ zak$ ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/zak/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/zak/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/zak/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/zak/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/zak/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/zak/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1


more output:

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

....

debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 135/256
debug2: bits set: 508/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 02:f8:78:65:22:75:23:44:c4:82:2a:8f:73:4b:f5:6a
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 02:f8:78:65:22:75:23:44:c4:82:2a:8f:73:4b:f5:6a.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: This question is very difficult to read and understand what you're asking. Try editing it to place your commands in a code block, with each entry on a separate line.

Comment: changing the question completely is not fair when there is already answer for the original question. Anyway I updated the answer accordingly, but this is really basic stuff that is described in *every* tutorial and how-to.

Comment: I tried to follow all of those how to tutorials, maybe I don't have the right one. Sorry, I am new to this. I did try to read and follow previous posts before asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

> debug1: identity file /Users/zak/.ssh/id_rsa type 1

This line tells you that the identity was loaded successfully.

> debug3: Could not load "/Users/zak/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key

This is just low-level notice, that the old key type was not recognized. This part is there for some historic reasons and is a bit confusing, but it is NOT an error, just debug3-level note.

---

The authenticity of the host is something totally different. The keys you generated are used for *authentication*, but the *authenticity* is assured by host keys.

If you wan to make sure that you are connecting to right host, copy the public hostkey from server to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` using different secure channel and you will not see this message again.

Answer (score 0):

ssh does not give special status to localhost; it is treated as just another host. Before ssh will connect to a host, it wants to know that it is connecting to the correct host. There is no way for ssh to be able to answer this *a priori*. You need to verify the host key and confirm it for ssh. At that time, ssh will save it in your known_hosts file. As Jakuje pointed out, you can also copy the key to this file manually.

For localhost, verifying the key is a little easier because it can be found locally in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub (on Red Hat-like systems; location will vary on other OS). Once you identify the host key file, you can get its fingerprint with:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f /path/to/host_key.pub
```

When you are asked to verify the host key, you can say yes if the fingerprint presented matches the one you computed.

When connecting to a host for the first time, you should determine the host's key fingerprint in advance; this is more challenging with remote hosts. The reality is that most people do not do this, but it is the correct thing to do.